Functions or formulas for Base-10 to Base-n (1<n<10)
Trying to find an answer to this question I was able to find a formula for the conversion of decimal numbers to their binary representations in Base-10 $D(x)$:
$$ D(x) = C_0 $$
$$ C_o = (C_{o+1} \cdot 10) + B_{2^{o}}(x+1)  $$
$$ B_{2^n}(x) = \frac{1 + (-1)^{A_{2^n}(x)}}{2} $$
$$ A_{2^m}(x) = \left( A_{2^{m-1}}(x) + \frac{1 + (-1)^{A_{2^{m-1}}(x) - 1}}{2} \right) \div 2 $$
$$ A_1(x) = x $$
So my question is: Are there functions for Base-10 to other Bases that doesn't use functions like step, floor, ceiling... (functions that doesn't seem to have a definition using the basic operations)?
My search shows me algorithms that one could use to convert decimal to base-n and functions with those functions mentioned.
Example $D(13)$ :
$$ A_1(13+1) = 14 \rightarrow B_1(13+1) = 1 $$
$$ A_2(13+1) = (14 + 0)/2 = 7 \rightarrow B_2(13+1) = 0 $$
$$ A_4(13+1) = (7 + 1)/2 = 4 \rightarrow B_4(13+1) = 1 $$
$$ A_8(13+1) = (4 + 0)/2 = 2 \rightarrow B_8(13+1) = 1 $$
$$ C_0 \approx ( ( ( ( ( (B_8(13+1)\cdot 10)  + B_4(13+1) )  \cdot 10 )  + B_2(13+1) )  \cdot 10 )  + B_1(13+1) $$
$$ C_0 \approx 1011 \approx D(13)$$

Do you have some examples? What are the inputs and outputs of $D$?

$D(0) = 0$ , $D(10) = 1010$ , $D(20) = 10100$ . I made this graph on Desmos (it is just an approximation of the $D(x)$ function)

Assuming natural number $x$, the $A$ functions look like some kind of ceiled division:
$$A_{2^m}(x) = \left\lceil\frac{A_{2^{m-1}}(x)}{2}\right\rceil$$

Assuming natural number $x$, the $B$ functions look like some kind of mod with complement:
$$B_{2^n}(x) = \left(A_{2^n}(x)+1\right) \bmod 2$$

See also OEIS A007088, assuming natural number $x$.

I see. But I am also looking for functions/formulas that doesn't use functions like floor, ceiling, mod, step...

And if one formula uses one of these types of functions I would then look for a definition/formula of this function using addition, multiplication, exponentiation, tetration... minus, division...

OK that limitation can be a fun challenge. Then since this question is about extending your idea to another base-$n$, think in terms of mod and ceiling, and replacing the $2$s by $n$s may be helpful. Then you can implement $\bmod n$ by recursion or exponentiation.

A more general version of the "selection function" $S_2(n) = (1+(-1)^n)/2$ is $S_m(n) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2k\pi i/m}$, giving $1$ when $n$ is a multiple of $m$ and $0$ otherwise. If you don't want the complex numbers, it can also be represented with $\cos$ terms.

@aschepler Your function gives the same result for every $n$, no?

Oops, right. It should be $S_m(n) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2kn\pi i/m}$

More on expressing the "selection function" $S_m(n)$ and $\bmod n$ by exponentiation: How to express the rest of division by three, with very elementary functions?

Expanding what I commented on @peterwhy 's answer I arrived at this solution that I think better approaches what I was looking for:
$$ A_1(x) = n - x$$
$$ A_{2^m}(x) = \left( A_{2^{m-1}}(x) + \frac{1 + (-1)^{A_{2^{m-1}}(x) - 1}}{2} \right) \div 2 $$
$$ R_n(x) = (x \cdot A_{2^\infty}) + (R_n(x-n) \cdot (1 - A_{2^\infty})) $$
$$ Q_n(x) = \frac{x - R_n(x)}{n} $$
$$ D(x) = (D(Q_n(x)) \cdot 10) + R_n(x) $$
Example $D(13)$ $n = 5$:
$$ A_1(13) = 5 - 13 = -8 $$
\begin{align*}
R_5(13) &= (13 \cdot 0) + (R_5(8) \cdot 1)     &&\to &Q_5(13) = \frac{13 - 3}{5} &= 2 \\
R_5(8)  &= (8 \cdot 0) + (R_5(3) \cdot 1)      &&\to &Q_5(8) = \frac{8-3}{5} &= 1\\
R_5(3)  &= (3 \cdot 1) + (R_5(-2) \cdot 0) = 3 &&\to &Q_5(3) = \frac{3-3}{5} &= 0\\
\end{align*}
$$ D(13) = (D(2) \cdot 10) + 3 $$
$$ D(2) = (D(0) \cdot 10) + 2 $$
$$ D(0) = (D(0) \cdot 10) + 0 $$
$$ D(13) = 23 $$

I see that the objective of $A_{2^m}(x)$ is to define a step function for $R_n(x)$ (at least for integer input $x$). But with such restriction, wouldn't $A_{2^m}(x)$ also need to be unified with some step function (to be implemented):
$$A_{2^m}(x) = {\left( A_{2^{m-1}}(x) + \frac{1 + (-1)^{A_{2^{m-1}}(x) - 1}}{2} \right) \div 2 \cdot \mathbf1_{m> 0}} + (n-x) \cdot \left(1-\mathbf1_{m> 0}\right)$$ ?

This is because $m$ can be a negative, right?
$$ A_1(x) = x = \left(A_{1/2}(x) + \frac{1+(-1)^{A_{1/2}(x) - 1}}{2} \right) \div 2 $$
$$ A_{1/2}(x) = 2x - \frac{1+(-1)^{A_{1/2}(x) - 1}}{2} $$

I mean the $A_1(x)$ defined in this answer, as $n-x$, which is not unified to one formula with $A_{2^m}(x)$. But such unification seems to be the whole point of defining this $A_{2^m}(x)$ used by $R_n(x)$.

Yes. But I defined the $A_1(x)$ and $R_n(x)$ in that way to remove the $0 \le x < n$ and $x \ge n$ conditions. Sorry for keeping putting restrictions and restrictions. My original idea was a function with recursion and basic operations, but now I think I am trying to look for a function with only recursion and basic operations. However, I am trying to unite the $A_1(x)$ and $A_{2^m}(x)$, since it doesn't look right in this separate way.

This is just a partial answer. Working on a definition for the mod and the floor functions
Using notation: $\operatorname{mod}(a,b)=a\pmod{b}$
Defining a function $c(v,b)$ that converts $v$ from base-$b$ to base-$10$
$$c\left(v,b\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{\operatorname{floor}\left(\log_{10}\left(v\right)\right)+1}\frac{b^{j}\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(v,10^{j+1}\right)-\operatorname{mod}\left(v,10^{j}\right)\right)}{10^{j}}$$
Using the previous function to define yet another function $C(v,b,n)$ to convert $v$ from base-$b$ to base-$n$
$$C\left(v,b,n\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\operatorname{floor}\left(\log_{n}\left(c\left(v,b\right)\right)\right)+1}10^{i}\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{c\left(v,b\right)}{n^{i}}\right),n\right)\right)$$
Desmos graph here

To continue with the recursive theme, define functions $Q_2$ and $R_2$ for non-negative integers $x$:
$$\begin{align*}
Q_2(x) &= \frac{x-R_2(x)}{2}\\
R_2(x) &= \begin{cases}
x, & 0\le x< 2\\
R_2(x-2), & x\ge 2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
Then your objective $D(x)$ can be redefined for non-negative integers $x$ as
$$D(x) = \left(D(Q_2(x))\cdot 10\right)+ R_2(x)$$
(These imply $D(0) = 0$.)
Replace every $2$ in the above lines by $n$ for the base-$n$.

Example $D(13)$:
$$\begin{align*}
R_2(13)&= 1 &&\to &Q_2(13) &= \frac{13-1}2 = 6\\
R_2(6)&= 0 &&\to &Q_2(6) &= \frac{6-0}2 = 3\\
R_2(3)&= 1 &&\to &Q_2(3) &= \frac{3-1}2 = 1\\
R_2(1)&= 1 &&\to &Q_2(1) &= \frac{1-1}2 = 0\\
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
D(13)
&= ((R_2(1)\cdot 10 + R_2(3))\cdot 10 + R_2(6))\cdot 10 + R_2(13)\\
&= 1101
\end{align*}$$

I really like this solution. The only thing that bothers me is the $R_n(x)$ definition.

@PageSteiner But $R_n(x)$ here is defined in a similar format as the $A_{2^m}(x)$. Exponentiation can be another way.

What do you mean by "format"? I was thinking of morphing the $R_n(x)$ function definition parts into one with $A_{2^\infty}(x)$  (for $A_1(x) = x$). Since it is 1 for positive numbers and 0 for negative numbers and zero, if $A_1(x) = 2-x$ then $A_{2^\infty}$ equals 1 for $x<2$ and 0 for $x>1$. The $R_2(x)$ could be defined as:
$R_2(x) = (x \cdot B_{2^\infty}) + (R_2(x-2) \cdot B_{2^\infty})$

$A_{2^\infty}(x)$ (for $A_1(x) = x$) is good for defining the absolute-value function:
$ |x| = x \cdot (2 A_{2^\infty} - 1) $

@PageSteiner Like $R_2(x) = B_1(x+1)$?

No. This would just oscillate between one and zero, no?

@PageSteiner But $R_2(x)$ is really oscillating between one and zero. As in $R_2(13) = R_2(11) = \ldots = R_2(1) = 1$.

Ah, I made a mistake there. $R_2(x) = (x \cdot A_{2^\infty}) + (R_2(x-2) \cdot (1-A_{2^\infty})) $ (for $A_1(x) = 2-x$). This way the second part is multiplied by 0 when $x<2$ and the first part is multiplied by 0 when $x>1$

Ahh, ok. Sorry. I understand now. But what about $R_3(x)$? It would oscillate between 0, 1, 2.

@PageSteiner Then you're looking for a function with period $3$, so not easy by real "basic operations", but possible by complex exponentiation or cosine (which is complex exponentiation). This is described in How to express the rest of division by three, with very elementary functions?.

@PageSteiner Back to my comment about "format": here $R_n(x)$ and $A_{2^m}(x)$ are both defined conditionally, with small base cases and large cases that references smaller cases. And $R_n(x)$ looks simpler with fewer symbols than $A_{2^m}(x)$, so may I know why should $R_2(x)$ be morphed into $A_{2^m}$ and even with $\infty$ involved?

I was trying to generalize $R_2(x)$ to $R_n(x)$. The $A_{2^m}$ functions outputs this sequences: $A_2(x) = 1, 1, 2, 2...$ $A_4(x) = 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2...$
And so on. So I thought "for $A_{2^\infty}(x)$ the output would be: 1, 1... for $x>0$ and ...0, 0 for $x<1$", then if I shifted this function I could make the output equals 0 for $x<2$ and 1 for $x>1$
$R_n(x) = (x \cdot A_{2^\infty}) + (R_n(x-n) \cdot (1-A_{2^\infty})$ for $A_1(x) = n - x$
I think it is more clear with examples:
$A_1(x) = 3-x$
$R_3(1) = (1 \cdot 1) + (R_3(1-3) \cdot 0)$
$R_3(5) = (5 \cdot 0) + (R_3(5-3) \cdot 1) $

@PageSteiner By replacing every $2$ by $n$, $$\begin{align*}
R_n(x) &= \begin{cases}
x, & 0\le x< n\
R_n(x-n), & x\ge n
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
